# Lucky Bamboo and Water

Tags: lucky-bamboo

As boiling water helps take the chlorine out of the water but not chloramine, is chloramine bad for lucky bamboo? As I thought it would be easier for me to boil the water and let it cool and then place my lucky bamboo in it with some lucky bamboo feed.

Answer (score 1):

Boiling will not remove chloramine.  Some plants are sensitive to the chlorine so your options are:

- filtered water using a carbon filter
- distilled water  (no dissolved ions so not a good choice long term)
- rain water
- tap water plus a chloramine neutralizer.  This can be purchased in any shop that sells things for pet fish.